# 'ios' : is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++, file, iostream

I am trying to write a matrix to a file with the above code. But i got the following error:
'ios' : is not a class or namespace name. My code:

```
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("C:/Users/zenitis/Desktop/bots/Nova/data/ownStatus.txt", ios::out | ios::app);               

for (int i = 0; i< 21; i++){
    myfile << featureMatrix[i] << "          ";
}
myfile << "\n";
myfile.close();
```

Any idea about this problem??

Comment: `std::ios::out`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ios` is a member of `std`. That is, you want to use one of the following approaches to refer to it:

```
using namespace std; // bad
using std::ios;      // slightly better

int main() {
    std::ofstream myFile("name", std::ios::app); // best
}
```

BTW, you can `open()` the `std::ofstream` directly in the constructor. Also, for `std::ofstream` the flag `std::ios_base::out` (the opening flags are actually defined in `std::ios`'s base class `std::ios_base`) is added automatically.

Comment: `using namespace` is OK in the function itself, but in headers and the entire code fine, no.

Comment: A using directive or a using declaration outside a function definition are definitely out of question in headers. Whether it is acceptable in source files (after including all headers) is a matter of taste. Personally, I don't like either of them and I tend to use full qualifications unless the name in question intended to potentially be found via argument dependent look-up.

Comment: Can't you also use I. In the function itself `int main() { using std::ios::out;`

Answer (score 6):

It is actually `std::ios::out`.